# Command to draw arc issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, syntax

I have the following code defined outside `\begin{document}`:

```latex
\newcommand{\point}[2] {
    ({#1}, {#2})
}

\newcommand{\arcpoints}[6] {
    ({#1}:{atan((#5 - #3)/(#4 - #2))}:{#6})
}
```

I am getting an error when drawing the arc on the line **above** `\end{tikzpicture}`:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=black}, show background rectangle]
    \newcommand{\f}[1] {
        {#1*#1 - #1/2 + 1/2}
    }

    \draw[transparent] (-1, -1) grid (3, 3);
    \draw[->] (-1, 0) -- (3, 0);
    \draw[->] (0, -1) -- (0, 3);

    \draw[dotted] \point{1/4}{\f{1/4}} -- \point{1/4}{0};
    \draw[dotted] \point{3/2}{0} -- \point{3/2}{\f{3/2}};

    \draw[dotted] \point{0}{\f{1/4}} -- \point{1/4}{\f{1/4}};
    \draw[dotted] \point{0}{\f{3/2}} -- \point{3/2}{\f{3/2}};

    \node[scale=0.6] at \point{1/4}{-0.25} {$x$};
    \node[scale=0.6] at \point{3/2}{-0.25} {$x + h$};

    \node[scale=0.6, left] at \point{-0.1}{\f{1/4}} {$f\left(x\right)$};
    \node[scale=0.6, left] at \point{-0.1}{\f{3/2}} {$f\left(x + h\right)$};

    \draw[blue, thin] \point{1/4}{\f{1/4}} -- \point{3/2}{\f{1/4}};
    \draw[blue, thin] \point{3/2}{\f{1/4}} -- \point{3/2}{\f{3/2}};
    \draw[scale=1, domain={-1}:{1/4*(1 + 41^(1/2))}, smooth, variable=\x, thick] plot ({\x}, {\f{\x}});
    \draw[red, thin] \point{3/2}{\f{3/2}} -- \point{1/4}{\f{1/4}};

    \fill[red, smooth] \point{1/4}{\f{1/4}} circle (1.25pt);
    \fill[red, smooth] \point{3/2}{\f{3/2}} circle (1.25pt);

    \draw[green, smooth] \point{1/4 + 0.3}{\f{1/4}} arc \arcpoints{0}{1/4}{\f{1/4}}{3/2}{\f{3/2}}{0.3};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, it seems to work when I write:

```latex
\draw[green, smooth] \point{1/4 + 0.3}{\f{1/4}} arc \arcpoints{0}{1}{1}{2}{2}{0.3};
```

**How can I fix this problem and what is wrong with my syntax?**

Comment: Hi! Could you please prepare a *minimal* complete code that fails? (BTW, why using `\point{a}{b}` when `(a,b)` would work?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see, your problem is already solved by @rmano answer (+1), however, I wouldn't recommend your approach of drawing your image.

- It make (according to my opinion) make image code longer and less clear. Compare the following two notation defining coordinates in your picture:

```
    \point{0}{f(14)}
          (0,{f(14)})
```

both defines the same coordinate.

- For drawing angle designation Ti*k*Z has defined library `angles` by which you can simple draw it. Compare both code:

```
\draw[green, smooth] \point{1/4 + 0.3}{(1/4)} arc \arcpoints{0}{1/4}{f(1/4)}{3/2}{f(3/2)}{0.3};
\pic [draw=green, semithick, radius=7mm] {angle = C--A--B};
```

where coordinates A, B and C can be defined at drawing dotted blue lines (see code and image below).

Considering aforementioned and (re)define your picture elements style, I suggest (for learn LaTeX and Ti*k*Z) to start with the following MWE (Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your image:

```
\documentclass[border=3.142592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                backgrounds
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
background rectangle/.style={fill=yellow!20},           % <---
show background rectangle,
tcklbl/.style = {inner sep=1pt, font=\tiny},      % <---
declare function = {f(\t)=((\t)^2 - \t/2 + 1/2);}       % <===
                        ]
% axis, grid
\draw[gray=50, very thin] (-1, -1) grid (3, 3);
\draw[->] (-1, 0) -- (3, 0);
\draw[->] (0, -1) -- (0, 3);
% function
\draw[thick] plot[samples=51, variable=\x,
                  domain=-1:1.8507] (\x, {f(\x)});
% points on function
\draw[densely dotted, blue] 
    (0,{f(1/4)}) node[tcklbl,left] {$f(x)$}     -| coordinate (A) (1/4,0) node[tcklbl,below] {$x$};
\draw[densely dotted, blue] 
    (0,{f(3/2)}) node[tcklbl,left] {$f(x{+}h)$} -| coordinate (B) (3/2,0) node[tcklbl,below] {$x{+}h$};
\draw[semithick, blue]      (B) |- coordinate (C) (A);
\draw[semithick, red,fill]  (A) circle[radius=1pt] -- (B) circle[radius=1pt];
%
\pic [draw=green, semithick, radius=7mm] {angle = C--A--B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
In upper MWE the upper limits od function domain is calculated by calculator, but if you like to exercise, how to do this inside image code, than explore `math` library (Ti*k*Z & PGF manual, chapter 94 Mathematical Expressions (pp. 1029).

By use of `\pgfmathsetmacro{<macro name>}{<expression>}` you can calculate as follows:

- function: $f(x) = x^2 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$
  \item $x$ where $f(x)=3$ can be calculated by:

```
    \begin{align*}
x^2 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2} & = 3 \Rightarrow   \\
                   2x^2 - x - 5 & = 0 \Rightarrow   \\
                              x & = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - 4\cdot2\cdot (-5)}}{2\cdot2}    \\
                                & = \frac{1 + \sqrt{41}}{4} = \boxed{1.8507}
   \end{align*}
```

Considering above, the following changes in MWE should be done:

- after `tikzpicture` options add

```
% right limit of domain:
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rbd}{(1 + sqrt(1 - 4*2*(-5)))/4}% axis, grid
```

- code lines for drawing of the function replace width:

```
% function
\draw[thick] plot[samples=51, variable=\x,
                  domain=-1:\rbd] (\x, {f(\x)});    % see \rbd
```

Comment: Very nice, +1! I would add a `fill=yellow!20` to the node writing "f(x+h)" to make it more legible.

Comment: @Rmano, thank you very much! Regarding to make tick labels more legible, hm, probably I should make text black. So far I will left answer as it is (meanwhile I added addendum with short explanation how domain limits can be calculated) . I hope that it is good starting point to OP further exploration of Ti*k*Z package :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about what you are trying to do here, but --- macro expansion in paths is not straightforward --- a macro is not a function, so you can have strange surprises (for example, `#1^2` if passed `-2` becomes `-2^2` which will give -4...).

I would use a function, really:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\point}[2] {
    ({#1}, {#2})
}

\newcommand{\arcpoints}[6] {
    ({#1}:{atan((#5 - #3)/(#4 - #2))}:{#6})
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={
        f(\x)=(\x)*(\x)-(\x)/2+1/2;
    },]
\draw[dotted] \point{1/4}{f(1/4)} -- \point{1/4}{0};
    \draw[dotted] \point{3/2}{0} -- \point{3/2}{f(3/2)};
    \draw[green, smooth] \point{1/4 + 0.3}{(1/4)} arc \arcpoints{0}{1/4}{f(1/4)}{3/2}{f(3/2)}{0.3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

...although I still do not understand the point of `\point`... (pun intended ;-))

Comment: That’s good to know! Thanks a lot. The `\point` was just an attempt to learn how everything works. I also did not know you could declare a function. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Sorry, your MWE throw error: `Undefined control sequence.
<argument> {1/4}, {\f 
                      {1/4}}
l.14 \draw[dotted] \point{1/4}{\f{1/4}}
                                        -- \point{1/4}{0};
? `

Comment: As ever @Zarko is right (forgot to transform a couple of `\f{}` to `f()`!)

Comment: @Rmano wouldn't `(1/4, f(1/4))` throw an error though?

Comment: Yes, you need `(1/4, {f(1/4)})`. I got used to add the brace always when I use a `pgfmath` expression there, for consistency: `({1/4},{f(1/4)})`